# Regex to strip leading zeros in dashed phone numbers

Tags: regex

I have some phone numbers with their corresponding names in a comma (CSV) format. I want to write them in this form, the program next will then transmit the numbers with tags to the database. I know it is possible in excel but for my own convenience regex is better.

I have almost completed the expression, there's some mistake with boundaries that are generating the bad results

---

([Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/wIrJms/1)) -- **For Online Check**

### Here's the expression:

```
\b0*([1-9-][0-9-]*|0)\b|([A-Z ]*)
```

### Want to replace the text like this:

```
SKT:\n\DC:\nADT:\n0$1\n$2
```

### Here's the text example:

```
0302-8447950,FAISAL SHAHZAD,0332-4941510,VIVO OFFICE
```

### Text Result Should be Like this

```
SKT: 
DC: 
ADT: 
0302-8447950
FAISAL SHAHZAD

SKT: 
DC: 
ADT: 
0332-4941510
VIVO OFFICE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does `0*([\d-]+),([A-Z ]+),{0,1}` work for you?

https://regex101.com/r/LRTFm0/2